# Netduino or Gadgeteer running IIS and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: netduino, .net-gadgeteer

Is it possible to deploy ASP.NET MVC3 applications onto either a Netduino or .NetGadgeteer? If so how would I go about such a thing?

What I want to do is have a Netduino, connected to a wifi router, that will host an MVC web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not support it. In order to run ASP.Net, you need to have some kind of IIS running. It is quite simple to serve HTML on HTTP on .Net Micro framework, but in order to use ASP, you need either a full fledged IIS server or some kind of embedded ASP server, like the one in Visual Studio (Cassini was the code name, I think).

You basically  4 choices:

- Find an embedded ASP server. There is a .net project called [aspnetserve](http://code.google.com/p/aspnetserve/) that can serve ASP pages, you may be able to port is to the Micro Framework.
- Step up to Windows CE, which can host ASP .Net pages.
- Serve plain HTML pages that you build on the spot.
- Use a templating engine other than ASP and port it to .Net MF if needed

Answer (score 3):

Both Gadgeteer and Netduino run the .Net Micro Framework which will not support an ASP.NET MVC web application.

[People have implemented simple web servers inside Netduino.](http://netduinohacking.blogspot.com/2011/03/netduino-plus-web-server-hello-world.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to host the MVC website on your Netduino or do you have a computer/device available to host the website and simply have your controllers communicate directly with the Netduino?

There's a great article on doing exactly this at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344471/Using-jQuery-Mobile-with-MVC-and-Netduino-for-Home